# Could not locate bindings file

Tags: node.js

I followed this [Adafruit IO basics tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-io-basics-digital-output/raspberry-pi) and everything installs fine, 
but when I want to start it (`node digital_out.js`) it tells me it can't locate the bindings file.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you run these two commands cd adafruit-io-basics/raspberry-pi  and npm install and let us know what happens?

Comment: You mean `cd adafruit-io-basics/raspberry-pi`, then `npm install` don't you @SteveRobillard - this mark-up gets awkward sometimes doesn't it! 8-)